# How to save XML data in table using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to store xml data in my database table using a stored procedure but data is not saving, I am not getting how can I do this..

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Users>
  <User ID="11005477969327">6/3/2011</User>
  <User ID="11034688201594">5/18/2011</User>
</Users>
```

My stored procedure is

```
Alter PROCEDURE [ProcessMailNotificationSentToUsers]
@User_XML XML
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @hdoc     int
DECLARE @doc      varchar(2000)

SET @doc = ''
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc

--OPEN XML example of inserting multiple customers into a Table.
INSERT INTO PasswordExpiryNotificationLog (UserId)
SELECT UserId FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Users/User',2)
WITH(
 UserId bigint
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
END
```

And my c# code here

```
SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[1];
try
{
   SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection());
   string strProc = "ProcessMailNotificationSentToUsers";

   arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@User_XML", SqlDbType.Xml);
   arrParam[0].Value = userXML;

   SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, strProc, arrParam);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: It's store*D* procedure - as **stored** in SQL Server - it has nothng to do with a "store* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this stored procedure instead (using SQL Server 2005 XQuery instead of the old legacy `OpenXML` code):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcessMailNotificationSentToUsers
    @User_XML XML
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.PasswordExpiryNotificationLog (UserId)
        SELECT 
      Tbl.Col.value('@ID', 'bigint')
        FROM
           @User_XML.nodes('/Users/User') AS Tbl(Col)
END
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Why `(@ID)[1]` instead of `@ID`?

Comment: @RubensFarias: you're right - for an attribute, that `[1]` is not even needed - thanks for pointing out! Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simplest Way to do is to write XML data into bytes and save them into a field in SQLServer

```
//One By One Function
Sub Main()
    Dim dsData As DataSet = GetDataSet()
    Dim xmlData As [String] = ConvertDataTableToXML(dsData.Tables(0))
    Dim barray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlData)
    Dim byteconstructedstring As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(barray)
    Dim xmltable As DataTable = stringxmltods(byteconstructedstring)

End Sub
//GetDataSet.....
Private Function GetDataSet() As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Test")

    dt.Columns.Add("id", Type.[GetType]("System.Int64"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.[GetType]("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Description", Type.[GetType]("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("Qty", Type.[GetType]("System.Int64"))

    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("id") = 1
    dr("Name") = "Red Stone"
    dr("Description") = "Stones"
    dr("Qty") = "10"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("id") = 2
    dr("Name") = "Blue Stone"
    dr("Description") = "Stones"
    dr("Qty") = "60"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("id") = 3
    dr("Name") = "Marbell"
    dr("Description") = "Stones"
    dr("Qty") = "6"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    dr = dt.NewRow()
    dr("id") = 4
    dr("Name") = "Graynite"
    dr("Description") = "Hard Stones"
    dr("Qty") = "60"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Return ds
End Function
//Get Table to XML
Private Function ConvertDataTableToXML(ByVal dtData As DataTable) As String
    Dim dsData As New DataSet()
    Dim sbSQL As StringBuilder
    Dim swSQL As StringWriter
    Dim XMLformat As String
    Try
        sbSQL = New StringBuilder()
        swSQL = New StringWriter(sbSQL)
        dsData.Merge(dtData, True, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey)
        dsData.Tables(0).TableName = "SampleDataTable"
        For Each col As DataColumn In dsData.Tables(0).Columns
            col.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute
        Next
        dsData.WriteXml(swSQL)
        XMLformat = sbSQL.ToString()
        Return XMLformat
    Catch sysException As Exception
        Throw sysException
    End Try
End Function
//stringxmltods
Public Function stringxmltods(ByVal xmlstring As String) As DataTable
    Dim theReader As New StringReader(xmlstring)
     Dim theDataSet As New DataSet()
     theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader)
     Return theDataSet.Tables(0)
 End Function
```